# How can I check the status of the specific job that was send to HTcondor?

Tags: condor

Is there a way to check the status of the specific job (e.g by cluster/process id) and how to retrieve those ids when job is submitted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For further reference i solved this by [Condor's ClassAd Mechanism](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v7.6/4_1Condor_s_ClassAd.html).

I inserted a custom ClassAd attribute in my condor.submit file:

```
+customAttribute = myID;
```

Then i can check for example JobStatus for this Job by:

```
condor_q -constraint 'customAttribute == myID' -f "%s" JobStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible without requiring a custom ClassAd, as per micco's suggestion (though I can envisage situations where this would be desirable).

You can provide the condor_q command with either a cluster/process ID to return its status, e.g. the following to return the status of job 5:

```
condor_q 5
```

Furthermore, if you are submitting clusters of jobs, you can retrieve the status of particular jobs within the batch using the following e.g. for task 123 within cluster 5:

```
condor_q 5.123
```